# Is there a Vim plug-in similar to fuzzyfinder_textmate and Command-T which does _not_ require Ruby support?

Tags: vim

Both of these plugins require Vim to be compiled with Ruby support, need to be compiled themselves using the same version of Ruby, etc. Is there a plugin which does the same job, but doesn't require installation other than dropping it into `vimfiles` directory?

UPDATE: These plugins allow to open files/buffers by typing characters which appear in their path, not necessarily in a row. I.e. if your directory has files

```
foo/bar.txt
foo/baz.vim
zee.c
```

you can type

```
,t f
```

and only two matching files are shown; after you add `r`, only one file is left and it can be opened by pressing `<Return>`.

Comment: the interesting think in your question is that even if one knows something that suits your needs, if he does not know fuzzyfinder_textmate and Command-T, you won't get any answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554719/find-a-file-in-vim/3561003#3561003 has some interesting answers for how to quickly open a file, not specifically in the Command-T way.  Several don't require plugins to vim at all, you might find something you like there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the latest fuzzyfinder vim plugin you can use

:FufCoverageFile

to mimic the global search features of fuzzyfinder_textmate and Command-T. No ruby needed.

Need also to have vim >= 7.2

Answer (score 3):

I used [LustyExplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1890) which provides similar functionality to the plugins you mention. Unfortunately it also requires ruby.

Later I started using [LycosaExplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3659) which is based on LustyExplorer but uses python instead of ruby. I prefer this one to LustyExplorer because I cannot compile vim against ruby in windows and with python I can do it fine.

Recently I started using [ctrlp.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3736) which also allows you to do something similar to what you request and doesn't require external depedencies (ruby or python). It seems to me that it is slower than LycosaExplorer on folders with a large number of files.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few plugins in this same thematics. fuzzyfinder may be the most ergonomic though.

I've listed some of them on the description page of [searchInRuntime](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/searchInRuntime) (that also helps opening  files)

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

[ctrlp](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/) is a good one.  It's used a lot, if for no other reason than it's in [janus.vim](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind python dependency， [LeaderF](https://github.com/Yggdroot/LeaderF) is a good choice. The performance on large project appears very well compared with some similar plugins.