# Iterating over directories to find pom.xml file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Currently, I have a command that loops over a list of directories(which I don't know the names of) and then `cd` into directory to finally execute a `maven install` command. However, I noticed that only one directory holds the `pom.xml`. It is unnecessary to run the maven command on those other directories. Is there a way to loop through directories and stop in the one that holds the `pom.xml`, then execute the maven command and break out of the loop?

```
for d in */ ; do (cd "$d" && maven install -Dmaven.test.skip=true); done
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I recursively find all files in current and subfolders based on wildcard matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5905054/608639), [Recursively find all files that match a certain pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23207896/608639), [Find file in directory from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/656741/608639), etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace your loop with the `find` command. For example:

```
find * -name pom.xml -execdir maven install -Dmaven.test.skip=True \;
```

See the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) for details.  The `-execdir` option runs the given command(s) inside the directory containing `pom.xm`.  This will recurse through your entire directory tree; to make it more exactly equivalent to your shell script, you can limit the depth to which it will descend:

```
find * -name pom.xml -maxdepth 1 -execdir maven install -Dmaven.test.skip=True \;
```

Comment: Any idea why i get this `find: The relative path $Path is included in the PATH environment variable, which is insecure in combination with the -execdir action of find.  Please remove that entry from $PATH` ? I am running the command through a jenkins groovy script inside a `workspace`

Comment: [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621132/why-using-the-execdir-action-is-insecure-for-directory-which-is-in-the-path) is an explanation about why `-execdir` is a problem if you are iterating through directories that are included in your `$PATH`.